# How do I output the `micro` character python json.dumps

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-unicode

I'm not sure about the specific terminology to my problem, so let me describe the exact problem itself:

`test.csv`:

```
foo,char
"bar","µ"
```

`test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import json

with open('test.csv', mode='r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(json.dumps(row))
```

**Expected output:**

```
{"foo": "bar", "char": "µ"}
```

**Actual output:**

```
{"foo": "bar", "char": "\u00b5"}
```

---

I've tried adding `encoding='utf-8'` to `open()` but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: May I ask why you do want this?

Comment: @timegeb I have a file that contains a lot of chars like `µ`, and I want to save a file that contains `µ`, not `\u00b5`.